# Looking for a module to hit a tokenized URL when certain actions happen

Tags: 7

I'm working with an API from another software product. And the way to create/update records there is by hitting a specifically crafter URL.

Ex. https://sample.nodeurl.tld/save?xml&object=supporter&Email=mytest@email.com

Is there any way to do this with rules or via another module? Or does this have to be done through a custom coded module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rules HTTP Client](http://drupal.org/project/rules_http_client) module (+ [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) itself) will handle that:

> This module adds an action wrapping of drupal_http_request to use Rules for making http requests. It has many general uses, because the Hypertext Transfer Protocol is the foundation of web data communication.

Comment: Fantastic! I think this will work. Thank you so much.